# How can I write named list to files (with the list names) with purrr

Tags: r, purrr, cat

Each (named) element of my list is a character string. How can I write those strings at ones with purrr?

For a single element I use this code:

```
cat(list[[1]], file = paste0(names(list)[1], ".txt"))
```

or

```
cat(list[[1]], file = names(list)[1]))
```

if I name the list directly with the extension.

I expect to write all files at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imap` is build for this.

```
purrr::imap(lst, ~cat(.x, file = paste0(.y, ".txt")))
```

From `?imap`

> is short hand for map2(x, names(x))

So you can also do

```
purrr::map2(lst, names(lst), ~cat(.x, file = paste0(.y, ".txt")))
```

Or in base R

```
mapply(function(x, y) cat(x, file = paste0(y, ".txt")), lst, names(lst))
```

Comment: You can also pass named arguments to `mapply`/`Map` I think. I haven't tested it but `Map(cat, lst, file=paste0(names(lst),".txt"))` should work.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `iwalk`

```
library(purrr)
iwalk(lst, ~ cat(.x, paste0(.y, ".txt")))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
lapply(names(lst), function(nm) cat(lst[[nm]], paste0(nm, ".txt")))
```

Comment: Agree with you, `map` is for producing objects, `walk` is for side effects.